# D3 v4 - Detect click coordinates in zoomed area

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am going to build some kind of ui to manage dependencies between blocks with d3 version 4.

I need to add new element onClick - it works fine, but if container element is zoomed in/out - coordinates of click are wrong, of course.

There should be well defined approach to do that, but I cannot find example for version 4 of d3 library. Will appreciate any help.

Illustration of problem:
https://bl.ocks.org/bfunc/e8c5649f1a3233b4141b36f6ffdff79c

**Edited:**

Solution:
https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/3e3e5333ff24a2c9972bc9320dc6f712/f4dcd09a07b5eafdc78efa0cf45948021e003739

Solution provided by [Gerardo Furtado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5768908/gerardo-furtado)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to track all the zoom and panning, you can create an object...

```
let zoomTrans = {x:0, y:0, scale:1};
```

... which you update in the zoom function:

```
zoomTrans.x = d3.event.transform.x;
zoomTrans.y = d3.event.transform.y;
zoomTrans.scale = d3.event.transform.k;
```

Then, in the click function, use this math:

```
let x = (d3.event.x - zoomTrans.x)/zoomTrans.scale;
let y = (d3.event.y - zoomTrans.y)/zoomTrans.scale;
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/3e3e5333ff24a2c9972bc9320dc6f712/f4dcd09a07b5eafdc78efa0cf45948021e003739

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again for  clear answer.